# Rails 4 LIKE query - ActiveRecord adds quotes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to do a like query like so

```ruby
def self.search(search, page = 1 )
  paginate :per_page => 5, :page => page,
    :conditions => ["name LIKE '%?%' OR postal_code like '%?%'", search, search],   order => 'name'
end
```

But when it is run something is adding quotes which causes the sql statement to come out like so

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "schools" 
WHERE (name LIKE '%'havard'%' OR postal_code like '%'havard'%')):
```

So you can see my problem.
I am using Rails 4 and Postgres 9 both of which I have never used so not sure if its and an activerecord thing or possibly a postgres thing.

How can I set this up so I have like `'%my_search%'` in the end query?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Your placeholder is replaced by a string and you're not handling it right.

Replace

```ruby
"name LIKE '%?%' OR postal_code LIKE '%?%'", search, search
```

with

```ruby
"name LIKE ? OR postal_code LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"
```

Comment: Isn't this vulnerable to SQL Injection? I mean, are those `search` strings sanitized?

Comment: @jdscosta91 the `?` in the where will take care of sanitizing

Comment: @house9 instances of `%` and `_` inside `search` will not be sanitized, under this approach.

Comment: When using '?' in this way in rails it is converted to a parameterized query.  The data within the parameter isn't sanitized (the %) but it is impossible to change context out of the query and turn it into processed SQL statements.

Answer (score 53):

Instead of using the `conditions` syntax from Rails 2, use Rails 4's `where` method instead:

```
def self.search(search, page = 1 )
  wildcard_search = "%#{search}%"

  where("name ILIKE :search OR postal_code LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search)
    .page(page)
    .per_page(5)
end
```

NOTE: the above uses parameter syntax instead of ? placeholder: these both should generate the same sql.

```
def self.search(search, page = 1 )
  wildcard_search = "%#{search}%"

  where("name ILIKE ? OR postal_code LIKE ?", wildcard_search, wildcard_search)
    .page(page)
    .per_page(5)
end
```

NOTE: using `ILIKE` for the name - postgres case insensitive version of LIKE

Comment: Is this still valid for Rails 5? Because if I have `Movie.where("title ILIKE :s", s: search_string)` it gets translated to `SELECT  1 AS one FROM "movies" WHERE (title ILIKE 'test') LIMIT $1` by ActiveRecord (Rails 5.1.6) - please notice that there is no percentage symbol after the ILIKE)

Comment: @sekmo - it should work, percentage would go in the `search_string` variable. I think the `SELECT 1 AS one` output is in rails console only or you are using `limit(1)`? FYI: Rails 5.1.6 has security issues, use 5.1.6.2 or 5.1.7 instead

Answer (score 24):

While string interpolation will work, as your question specifies rails 4, you could be using Arel for this and keeping your app database agnostic.

```
def self.search(query, page=1)
  query = "%#{query}%"
  name_match = arel_table[:name].matches(query)
  postal_match = arel_table[:postal_code].matches(query)
  where(name_match.or(postal_match)).page(page).per_page(5)
end
```

Comment: Should really be easy to create a func to do this dynamically with a list of attributes

Comment: Untested, though it could be something like this: scope search_attributes, ->(query, attributes){
  arel_attributes = attributes.map{|a| arel_table[a]}
  arel_queries = arel_attributes.map{|a| a.matches(query)}
  return where(arel_queries.reduce{|res,q| res.or q})
}

Answer (score 8):

ActiveRecord is clever enough to know that the parameter referred to by the `?` is a string, and so it encloses it in single quotes. You *could* as one post suggests use Ruby string interpolation to pad the string with the required `%` symbols. However, this might expose you to SQL-injection (which is bad). I would suggest you use the SQL `CONCAT()` function to prepare the string like so:

`"name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR postal_code LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')", search, search)`

Comment: I just implemented this in an application and it worked great.  Thank you John.

Comment: regarding injections, no it does not and in any case this makes no difference. The string is inserted into the sql and rails should have validated it before (doesn't matter if a `%` is appended/prepended or not). Either it works as expected or rails has a major bug affecting both cases.

Answer (score 7):

If someone is using column names like `"key"` or `"value"`, then you still see the same error that your mysql query syntax is bad. This should fix:

```
.where("`key` LIKE ?", "%#{key}%")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 def self.search(search, page = 1 )
    paginate :per_page => 5, :page => page,
      :conditions => ["name LIKE  ? OR postal_code like ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%"],   order => 'name'
  end
```

See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html?#conditions) on AREL conditions for more info.

Answer (score -1):

```
.find(:all, where: "value LIKE product_%", params: { limit: 20, page: 1 })
```