# What does the "%#{variable}%" syntax mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What does the `"%#{}%"` more specifically the `%`. I know that `"#{variable}" is simply string interpolation, but what about the`%`?

I am implementing a simple search form similar to [Rails 4 LIKE query - ActiveRecord adds quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105706/rails-4-like-query-activerecord-adds-quotes-problems).

Does it have to do with ActiveRecord or the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% is a wild card for SQL that represent any characters. So if you need to find anything that includes blahblah for instance,  you search for %blahblah%.

Comment: Could you say it is similar to Regex in pattern matching?

Comment: If you omit both percent signs, SQL will try to make an exact match. You can use "blahblah%" to effect a "starts with" match, and "%blahblah" to effect "ends with."