# Rails .where query not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, grape-api

I have a table called Toys that has the columns `toy_id, company_id, store_id, name and description`

I am trying to do a query on the table like the following:
`toys = @company.toys.where("store_id = ? AND (name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)", params[:store_id], params[:query], params[:query]`

The idea is if the user goes to the following url: `https://myapp.com/api/toys/search?store_id=8&query="robot"` that it will return all the toys for the store denoted by `store_id` that have a `name` or `description` LIKE `robot`. Each time it returns empty JSON. Not exactly sure why? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: try this `toys = @company.toys.where("store_id = ? AND (name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)", params[:store_id], "%#{params[:query]}%", "%#{params[:query]}%"`.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: `?` in the where will take care of sanitizing

Comment: @axlj he is receiving param query not name or description. https://myapp.com/api/toys/search?store_id=8&query="robot"

Comment: If you look at the url, I want ```:query``` to be used to match against the ```toy.description``` and ```toy.name```.

Comment: its not vulnerable to sql injections http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105706/rails-4-like-query-activerecord-adds-quotes

Comment: Okay, it still didn't work though :(

Comment: what does your console SQL look like ?

Comment: @charlysisto I am trying to figure that out. I will reply with an answer shortly

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Your answer was correct! I was still passing in query like ```...&query="robot"``` when it should be ```...&query=robot``` since it is now being treated like a string in the api. Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the first comment in the original question by @PardeepDhingra

```
toys = @company.toys.where("store_id = ? AND (name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)", params[:store_id], "%#{params[:query]}%", "%#{params[:query]}%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Arel style:

```
companies = Company.arel_table

toys = @company.where(store_id: params[:store_id]).where(companies[:name].matches(params[:query]).or(companies[:description].matches(params[:query])))
```

Or even:

```
companies = Company.arel_table

search_query = companies[:name].matches(params[:query]).or(companies[:description].matches(params[:query]))

toys = @company.where(store_id: params[:store_id]).where(search_query)
```

Comment: I will give this a try

Answer (score 1):

As You 'have a table called Toys', You could try something like this:

```
@toys = Toy.where("company_id = ? AND store_id = ? AND (name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)", params[:company_id], params[:store_id], params[:query], params[:query]
```

I hope it will help You!