# How to pass search string to rails scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I've seen the example below but what does the `query: "%#{query}%"` mean?

```
  scope :by_query, ->(query, ...){
    joins(...).
    where(... OR
           ... ,
      query: "%#{query}%"
    )
  }
```

Comment: It's an SQL like operator. See [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105706/rails-4-like-query-activerecord-adds-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely *supposed* to be doing the sql `LIKE` operator, however, it's not:

```
query = 'something' 
User.where(query: "%#{query}%").to_sql
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
#    WHERE "users"."query" = '%something%'
```

It's just using the [hash conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) feature of Active Record's query interface to look for values that are equal to the value `%#{query}%` precisely. If it's supposed to be doing a `LIKE` query, you would need to be doing something like:

```
User.where("query LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").to_sql
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
# WHERE (query LIKE '%something%')
```