# Rails Controller where statement with Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

In my "main" controller I am trying to query the article table to find all the articles where the link (this is a field with article url) contains a specific domain.
I can't for the life of me figure it out.

It tried the below but get the following error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "link"

This is what I have in my controller:

```
@featured = Article.where("link.includes? 'example.com'")
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string parameter of `where` method is for your database engine as part of SQL, not for Ruby interpreter.

So you should write it like:

```rb
@featured = Article.where('link LIKE ?', '%example.com%')
```

Here the `LIKE` is a SQL keyword.

See [Rails 4 LIKE query - ActiveRecord adds quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105706).

Comment: This worked a treat. Thank you so much for the answer and explanation.